# Returning -1 as value of variable;

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

When I try run the aplication, it shows the Index was outside the bounds of the array at line float[] u_f = a[userid]; when I check the value of userid, it is -1;
Any idea? 
PS. the user ID can be every integer,but I take the index of the integer with is between`(0, 1143600 for item)` and `(0, 89395 for user)` and my calculation is based on that.Then, my calculation is based on the index of `userid` value which is stored in array a not based on the value of `userid`. 
Thanks in advance.

```
        float[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 89395).Select(i => new float[100]).ToArray();
        float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
        int[] c = new int[1258038];
        int[] d = new int [92160];
        ........
        public float dotproduct(int userid, int itemid)
        {
            result = 0f;
            float[] u_f = a[userid];   //  <----Error Line (index was outside the bounds of array-The value of user id is -1)
            float[] i_f = b[itemid];

            for (int i = 0; i < u_f.Length; i++)
            {
                result += u_f[i] * i_f[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text))
            {
                    int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                    int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
                    int userseq=Array.IndexOf(d, sc);
                    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
                    }
                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
                    {
                        sb1.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", d[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
                        sb1.AppendLine();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());


            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text))
            {
                int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text);
                int userseq0 = Array.IndexOf(d, uid);
                int itemseq0 = Array.IndexOf(c, iid);
                dotproduct(userseq0, itemseq0);
                MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + itemseq0 + " is " + result);
            }
```

Comment: your question is confusing.

Comment: Do not try to vandalize your own question.  That is not appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
int userseq=Array.IndexOf(d, sc);
```

is presumably returning `-1` which you are then passing into your dotproduct function which is then causing it to fail. You need to decide on what logic to apply in the case that you can't find `sc` in `d` and implement that.

Though as others have said validating your input to dotproduct would help you find problems a bit more easily.

Comment: You right @Chris. May you give me a solution by add comments to my code,please?

Comment: @user3446681 the "solution" really depends on how you want your application to react on user input not matching the expected value. It's up to you to determine that.

Comment: Exactly as Crono says. You have an array of size 92160 that you are looking up the user input in. What should happen if they enter something not in that range? I can't tell you that. You have to tell us that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are asking. You have an error because you are try to access to the index -1 of a. An array begin at 0. The value -1 does not exist. `userid` should be between 0 and a.Length.

Comment: Exactly. OP needs to validate parameter input.

Answer (score 1):

Is your method *supposed* to accept a `userid` value that's inferior to zero? If so then you cannot use that to define an array's length. Period.

If -1 is not a valid value, I would add this right on the first line of your `dotproduct` method, since it's public:

```
if (userid < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("userid");
```

As for *why* it's -1 in the current context, as others pointed out if the text value you try to find in the `d` array isn't there, the `IndexOf` method will return -1. You will have to validate the user's input before calling in your method.

I will also say what I already told you in your other post: name your variables in a clear way and - if that makes sense in your scenario - use custom classes rather than jagged arrays. Your code will be far easier to read and maintain afterwards.

Comment: deleted my comment now. Will delete this in a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int userseq=Array.IndexOf(d, sc);
```

it returns -1 if item `sc` is not present in array `d`. Then you pass `userseq` variable as first argument of a function `dotproduct` and take array index by it's first argument (`userid`). So here is your problem - in the `IndexOf`.

I don't know how to fix it - it's your buiseness logic and you must decide how to handle the case when input data isn't present in array. Maybe show message to user immediately.